# Расскажите о способах посмотреть php-код с чужого сервера

Tags: php, база-данных, веб-программирование, безопасность, веб-сервер

Правильно ли я понимаю, что это невозможно, и таким образом, владелец сайта может безопасно хранить некоторые пароли прям в php-скриптах?

(Это я задумался о том, как сделать два php-скрипта на сервере, чтоб пользователь сайта мог запустить только один из них, а второй запускался бы первым.)

Comment: Всегда есть риск, что кто-то получит доступ к вашим скриптам, ничего не бывает безопасно. Исходя из этого, если желаете хранить пароли в php-скрипте, то не в открытом виде, а виде хеша.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey , но все-таки получение такого доступа не является какой-то стандартной задачей для нехакеров?

Comment: Во многом это зависит от квалификации сисадмина сервера. Сегодня любой «нехакер» может вооружиться готовым инструментарием и эксплуатировать уязвимость серверного ПО. Эти уязвимости выявляются ежедневно. Не говоря уже о том, что ваши же скрипты могут содержать одну из многих известных уязвимостей, а это уже касается вашей квалификации.

Comment: граждане, храните даньги, тоесть пароли в сберегательной книжке, тоесть в .env файлах. .env добавьте в gitignore, и запретите показывать его серверу.

Comment: @AlexKhonko назовите хоть одну причину, по которой .php файл будет хуже, чем .env? Его даже "запрещать показывать" не нужно

Comment: @lith.al **каждый** веб-сервер в интернете работает именно так: пользователь запускает один файл, а тот инклюдит второй. В итоге код из второго файла исполняется сначала. А доступен второй файл пользователю, или нет - это никого не волнует. Это если речь идёт, разумеется, о доступе к запуску файла. Если под доступом имеется доступ к коду, то говорить о какой-то "безопасности" просто бессмысленно.

Comment: @Ипатьев php хуже, потому что php может обработать веб сервер, а env - нет. Никто не сможет сломать веб-сервер, если у тебя ничего там не будет)

Comment: @AlexKhonko ну ок,  веб-сервер выведет содержимое env файла никак не обрабатывая, то есть как есть. **И в чём разница?** Некоторые околопохапешные суеверия меня поражают до глубины души, именно своей нелогичностью.